# How to get in Views RESTful API non latin's letters on fields?

Tags: 8

With this [guide](https://www.appnovation.com/blog/setup-drupal-8-restful-web-services-3-easy-steps), I do my RESTful API view (through core modules: RESTful Web Services and Serialization). Ater go to API page, I get this JSON:

```
[{"title":"\u0411\u044b\u0441\u0442\u0440\u044b\u0439 \u0431\u044e\u0434\u0436\u0435\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0424\u0440\u0438\u0437 \u041c\u0430\u0433 (Freeze Mage)"}]
```

All `\u0xxx` codes — it's non english/latin letters (Russian/Ukraine in UTF-8, for example).

How to correct (readable) display in JSON response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drupal 8 Rest module relies on the [Serialization](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/serialization) module to create the JSON output. This module, in turn, is using the [Serializer Symfony component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html), which outputs escaped characters by default (it is not passing the [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) constant to the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) call).

As far as I can see, the escaped UTF8 characters are fine (they are legal in JSON) and you should be able to parse it back to UTF8 from any REST client having a JSON decoder. They are just not very readable if you try to read the JSON directly.

Comment: Oh, thx for answer.